# CSS Border Style

Tags: html, css

How can I make a border style like my added image?
Look at the left bottom border, the border has some gaps.
How can I make that by CSS?

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KaJB.png)

Comment: css `border:1px dashed #000;`

Comment: You can make that by making the element have a white background. There is no way to 'break' the border into pieces though. Also, what have **you** tried? Did you even try to tackle this issue yourself?

Comment: No one cares if your need is urgent. It just doesn't matter to us.

Comment: Try to be polite bro @tora

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Torazaburo is quite right, Mohammed. It is a widespread view that asking volunteers for priority treatment is itself not polite. While we had a discussion on the matter (see the link), most readers who help do not think that discussion was necessary, since it should be unthinkable that we would get several readers a day wanting to transfer their urgency onto others. And yet we do.

Comment: @MohammadAsad Think carefully. In what sense is you assuming that your urgency would be of interest to anyone else, or affect their behavior, be "polite"? Actually, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Place your border on the main container and then absolutely position the "Anna Jessica" container with a white background to cover the border. Here is a general example based on your image:

```css
h2,
p {
  margin: 0px;
}

#test {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 15px 15px 75px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

#bump-out {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -38px;
  left: 70px;
}

#bump-out-img {
  padding: 0px 25px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
}

#bump-out-img:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 12px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

#bump-out-img img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#bump-out-title p {
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <div id="bump-out">
    <div id="bump-out-img">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" />
    </div>
    <div id="bump-out-title">
      <h2>
        Some Name
      </h2>
      <p>
        Some Position
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Waw you really went all-out and made the whole thing... Well done, although I feel the OP could have added some of his own code first.

Comment: Wow, I wanted to write "wow" myself, but @somethinghere was the 1st!

Comment: I absolutely agree. I actually posted a comment asking what he attempted first but the question kept getting up-voted. I figured there were others interested.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BSK